# Multilingual i18n library interfering with ajax calls

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, internationalization, routes

I'm using Codeigniter with the i18n library to build a multilingual website. I followed [this guide](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n) and it works fine.

The problem there is, apparently, in pages where I have to ajax calls, in jQuery, throug `$.getJson`.

```
console.log('1');
return  $.getJSON("photos/change_product", json_data, function(data) {
    console.log('2');
```

In this piece of code, for example, in the console it just prints "1". Using Firebug I see that the urls for the get calls look like these:

```
GET http://localhost/website/photos/change_product?product_id=1
GET http://localhost/website/en/photos/change_product
```

I tried disabling the library and the page worked as it should, so I'm pretty sure there's a conflict with this library, but I don't really know where to start looking. Any suggestion?

EDIT: I partially solved this. At least, I've found a workaround.
It seems like I should use the function `site_url()` inside the javascript, so that it creates the correct link, as explained in the library's wiki. Obviously I cannot use a php function inside a javascript file so, in a `view`, before loading the script, I put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteurl = "<?=dirname(site_url('a'))?>";
```

And now I have the path to prefix wherever I need it. It's just a bit ugly. Do you think is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

first you could use `window.location.pathname` to get `/website/en/photos/change_product` part and then some substr, or regexp to get current language and add it to called url if you don't want to add js into you php scripts, or add controller to:

```
  // special URIs (not localized)
    private $special = array (
        "admin"
    );
```

in `MY_Lang.php` file. That way, controller in that array will not be redirected if language prefix is missing. You can create controller for ajax calls and add it to the array, or rewrite a bit functions in `My_Lang` so it could check whole address and not only controller.